# jar file from j2me won't instal on my phone. Any idea why?

Tags: java-me, network-programming, wireless, j2mepolish

Today, I tried to install my first j2me file (jar file) on my phone, but I am getting the error below. Can any of you kindly explain me why and how I can fix this network error or what else I need to instal on my mobile. Basically, it is a demo sms application I got it from netbeans. I wanted to install on my mobile to try it as I need to develop a similar thing for my coursework. Thank you guys.

ERROR MESSAGE: "application cannot be installed. requires the use of a particular network resource to listen for network information. This network resource it's not supported on this device."

Comment: Hey Hi check this link, this may be help you.[How to Send Text SMS using J2ME](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_Send_Text_SMS_in_Java_ME)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, maybe someone else need it. the problem is that the network provider on the phone restricts this type of communication, we needed to have the url of their port or number of the provider "stations" to be able to install and run on my mobile. As I don't have that, I can just build my application and run from netbeans to demonstrate how it works.